# How to manage Standard pageLayout section on some conditions in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I Customize Case standard page layout i want to hide and show some section on condition bases

I have case Standard page layout and there a section Named "Appraisal Rebuttal" i want to hide and show this section on some conditions

Answer (score 0):

Create two different record types and have different pagelayouts assigned to each record type.Based on the condition have a workflow to change recordtype.Once recordtype changes layout will automatically change

Comment: @Mohith Kumar How can i asign record types based upon the field status..can you explain..

Comment: Use simple workflow rule or trigger to achieve this scenario.